# How to deploy a contract in web3.js

Tags: web3js

I am trying to deploy the contract using web3.js@1.2.6 
[image][image]i have mentioned the error and code that i have typed i m stuck in line 10

Comment: Gee, you couldn't think of a better way than taking a photo of your screen with a camera??? I can see the background of your room there. A screenshot is just one simpler option, which is also not reccommended here, since users cannot copy/paste parts of your code into their answers. A copy/paste of your code into the question is the preferred way for posting questions here. Please do so.

Comment: var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
web3.eth.accounts

code = fs.readFileSync('blockchain/voting.sol').toString()
solc = require('solc')
compiledCode = solc.compile(code)
abiDefinition = JSON.parse(compiledCode.contracts[':Voting'].interface)
VotingContract = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition)

Comment: This is d code i m trying and it gives error

Comment: Downvoted, pictures are not searchable, please add code.

Comment: https://github.com/amand1996/Votechain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, I didn't replicate the code. You should try to upload code blocks that would allow us to replicate your code fast.

Nevertheless, my guess is that the error on you line 10 is caused because of web3.eth.Contract(...)  expecting 2 arguments, ABI and Address of Contract, and you just gave it the ABI. Check the documentation and the following example they have [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#new-contract). Also, the function Contract is with a capital 'C'. Hope that helps

Comment: How to know the contract address

Comment: Check this https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to know the address of the contract you're deploying. You only need the address along with the ABI if you're trying to interact with an already deployed contract with web3.

Answer (score 1):

In web3.js v0.x, use `web3.eth.contract`.

In web3.js v1.x, use `new web3.eth.Contract`.

Comment: I have used it still it gives as web3.eth.contract is not a function

Comment: I used web3js@1.2.6

Comment: @KaarthigaAyyappan: Good. So you can use the second option, as suggested in my answer.